# Sufficient Condition for Positivity of Matrix with Operator-valued Entries

Tags: operator-theory, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be some Hilbert space, let $B(\mathcal{H})$ denote the bounded linear operators acting on $\mathcal{H}$, and let $M_n(B(\mathcal{H}))$ denote the $n \times n$ matrices with operator-valued entries. Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ be one such matrix. My question is,

> If $\sum_{i,j=1}^n u_i^* a_{ij} u_j$ is a positive semi-definite (PSD) operator in $B(\mathcal{H})$ for all $n$-tuples $(u_1,...,u_n)$ of unitary elements in $B(\mathcal{H})$, does this imply that $A$ is PSD in $M_n(B(\mathcal{H}))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $\xi\in \mathcal H^n$. Choose $r $ such that $\|\xi_r\|\geq\|\xi_j\|$ for all $j $.

For each $j$, let $x_j\in B(\mathcal H)$ be a contraction such that $x_j\xi_r=\xi_j $. By the argument in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2894737/22857), there exists a unitary with $u_j\xi_r=\xi_j$. Then 
$$
\langle A\xi,\xi\rangle=\sum_{k,j}\langle a_{kj}\xi_j,\xi_k\rangle=\sum_{k,j}\langle a_{kj}u_j\xi_r,u_k\xi_r\rangle=\left\langle\left(\sum_{k,j}u_k^*a_{kj}u_j\right)\xi_r,\xi_r\right\rangle\geq0. 
$$

Comment: I know I already upvoted this your answer, but I'm now discovering that I'm slightly confused by parts of it. First, shouldn't $\xi$ be a tuple in $B(\mathcal{H})^n$? Second, how are you able find those unitary elements. I tried proving this, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: No, $B (H)^n $ are $n $-tuples of operators, and $\xi $ is an  $n $-tuple of vectors. To construct a unitary,  it is enough to map one orthonormal basis to another. So to get $u_2$, take an onb that starts with $\xi_1$, and map it to an onb that starts with  $\xi_2$.

Comment: But what if $\xi_1, \xi_2,...,\xi_n$ each have different lengths? Then no unitary could send one of the vectors to another vector.

Comment: Good point. It is still possible with some care, using  a different argument.  Edited. Keep asking if you need to.